# ScriptEvalutionError : For Input string "" : When supplying a string as ID

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, tinkergraph

I have set up a docker container for tinkerpop/gremlin-server on my dev machine.

I have an .NET Core application that uses Gremlin.Net version 3.4.1

I connect to the localhost docker using IGremlinClient and when passing the following query to add a vertex:

```
g.addV("Root").property(id,"56b7ddc6-7629-42d4-b748-bfbce0992f13")
```

I then get the error:

```
ScriptEvaluationError: For input string: "56b7ddc6-7629-42d4-b748-bfbce0992f13"
```

When I run the query using the gremlin console the vertex is added:

```
gremlin> g.addV("Root").property(id,"56b7ddc6-7629-42d4-b748-bfbce0992f13")
==>v[56b7ddc6-7629-42d4-b748-bfbce0992f13]
```

How can I create a new vertex with a string as an Id when running through the IGremlinClient in my application?

Comment: are you using the default (i.e. no configuration changes) tinkerpop/gremlin-server docker container?

Comment: Yes I am. I have made no configuration changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the default Gremlin Server Docker container you are getting this [configuration](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.2/gremlin-server/conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties#L18) for your hosted TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
```

The `IdManager` is set to `LONG` so it will only accept input values that can be coerced to a `long`. You should change that setting to `UUID` perhaps given the string you are sending or perhaps `ANY`. You can read more about those options [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_4).

As a side note, I'd agree that the error message isn't helpful. Note that it has been [improved](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/commit/dcf9e070eac6cce7bd651c22059ecd8738f692d5#diff-c6ac525df9244502dc56f17d0006e6a0) for next release of 3.4.3/3.3.8.

Comment: What are the steps for doing this for my docker container?

Comment: Create a new `Dockerfile`, use TinkerPop's Docker image as a base, add a step that overwrites the configuration file and ultimately start a new container with your customized image.